# How to properly change mount point of the folder?

Tags: linux, fedora, partition, mount

I have a folder(mostly with postfix user mailboxes-homedirs) mounted on a disk A(raid1) and I want to move it from disk A to disk B(also raid1).

Currently it is like:

/h1(folder) /md120(diskA)

and I want:

/h1(folder) /md121(diskB)

should I simply umount and then mount to another disk?

**UPDATE 1**

Hi again!

Thank you guys for all your answers.

It seems that I was wrong in my question.

The proper would be

How to properly change mount point of the folder?

So I have /h1 mounted to /md120 and I want to change it's mount point to /md121.

**UPDATE 2**
mount -l

fstab doesn't contain mounting.

```
/dev/md121 on /home2

/dev/md125 on /h1
```

My idea is to move `h1` under `home2` so full path would be `/home2/h1`, which would be mounted into `/dev/121` and `/dev/md125` would be 'removed'. The problem is that `h1` contains user homedirs(mailboxes) so I think to simply `ln` after removing.

Comment: Are you really just looking for the `mv` command?

Comment: @kormoc, Hm, no, I guess. Because I need have the same folder but mounted on another device.

Comment: if both `/h1/md120` and `/h1/md121` are mounted, why wouldn't `mv /h1/md120/* /h1/md121/` work for your needs?

Comment: @kormoc, check the post update.

Comment: In the light of your update, could you edit the contents of `/etc/fstab` into the question?

Comment: @MadHatter, updated.

Comment: That's not `fstab`, but OK.  I fear your comments above contain so many misconceptions that I can't find a way to easily answer the question.  I really do recommend that you do some reading about how file systems, device access, and mounting work under Linux before you even decide what changes you'd like to make, much less start making them.  I'm **really** sorry if this sounds harsh or patronising - it's honestly not meant to be - but I fear you may shoot yourself in the foot really badly unless you get some understanding of what's going on first.

Comment: @MadHatter, well generally that's why I am asking for help here :) I understand clearly my lack of knowledge in Linux. So I appreciate your help. In general my goal is clearly stated in last 2 sentences of my post. Also bad thing is, that the system I currently deal with, was built in 2005 and then updated in 2010 or something, and the person who did this, lets say, can't give any piece of advice. But in general I think I will continue my research, if no over information will be opened here. TY.

Comment: The FAQ's pretty clear; SF is for people "needing expert answers related to managing computer systems in a professional capacity", and I'm not really sure this qualifies.  Nevertheless, I've said what I'd do, below; hopefully, it'll be of some use to you.

Comment: @MadHatter, then SuperUser suits best?

Comment: Or maybe `unix.stackexchange.com`; but don't just post the question again there.  If you want it moved, then flag this question for a moderator's attention, and ask them to move it.  They're usually very happy to do so.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `rsync` -

```
   rsync -a --progress --remove-source-files /src/dir1/ /dst
```

Comment: -v for constant reassurance and a warm fuzzy feeling =)

Comment: `--progress` will give you the same reassurance, a warm fuzzy feeling, and some more

Answer (score 2):

Are both raid partitions mounted? If they are you can use what you would normally do:

```
mv /h1 /h2
```

Make sure you stop postfix first.

Answer (score 0):

use [xar](http://code.google.com/p/xar/), this is better than all other as it preserves the original permissions, access times of files ... etc

Comment: Your link makes no sense... did you have the wrong URL in your clipboard by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

1. Quiesce the system.  This will probably mean rebooting single-user,
   and if you're right about those file systems not being mentioned in `/etc/fstab`,
   that  will also unmount them.  I'm assuming this does happen.
2. `mount /dev/md121 /home2`
3. `mkdir /home2/h1`
4. `mount /dev/md125 /home2/h1`

Everything that is currently under `/h1` will now appear under `/home2/h1`, which I think is what you want.